# Alternative solution for Azure Service Fabric distributed cache

Tags: azure, caching, system-design, service-fabric-stateful

I have an application running in Service Fabric with multiple nodes. All the running nodes share some cache data using distributed caching available in Service Fabric.

Now, I am looking to move out from Service Fabric due to cost issues.
What would be a good solution for me where I can also maintain caching between multiple instances ( like the distributed cache in Service Fabric).

I need to install it in an Azure environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an alternative managed by Microsoft, the best choice would be Azure Redis Cache.

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/